# High-multiplicity maximum-weight matching

Tags: algorithms, matching, assignment-problem

There are $n$ people and $m$ jobs. We would like to assign at most one job to each person.
For each person,job pair, there is a positive value determining the fitness of this person to that job. The goal is to find an assignment that maximizes the total value. So far, it is exactly the problem of finding a maximum-weight matching in a bipartite graph, which can be solved in time poly$(m,n)$.

Now, suppose that in each job there are $p$ identical positions: for each person, the fitness value is the same for all positions of the same job. The problem can be reduced to maximum-weight matching by constructing a new graph with $p$ clones of each job, and then running any algorithm for maximum-weight matching. The run-time would by poly$(m,n p)$. But this run-time is exponential in the length of the binary representation of $p$; it may be very wasteful when $p$ is large.

Is there a more efficient algorithm for this problem? Particularly, is there an algorithm that runs in time poly$(m, n, \log p)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using [min-cost flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem).

Construct a graph with a source vertex $s$, one vertex per person, one vertex per job, and one sink $t$.  Add edges as follows:

- Add an edge of capacity 1 from $s$ to each person, with cost 0.
- Add an edge of capacity 1 from each person to each job they are qualified for, with cost equal to the negative of their fitness.
- Add an edge of capacity $p$ (the number of positions per job) from each job to $t$, with cost 0.

Now find an integral solution to this min-cost flow problem.  There are polynomial-time algorithms for min-cost flow, which produce an integral solution.  That solution then solves your problem, as the amount of flow on the edge from a person to a job is 1 or 0 according to whether that person should be assigned to that job.

Comment: "Now find an integral solution to this min-cost flow problem" I have a hunch that if you find the solution without regards to whether it's integral, it will end up being integral - is that true?

Comment: @llllvvuu, I imagine that it depends on what algorithm you use.  If you use linear programming, there are no guarantees.  With some other combinatorial algorithms, you are guaranteed to get an integral solution.

Comment: Does the solution depend on the algorithm because the solution is non-unique?

Comment: Thanks! I think this solution can even be extended to many-to-many matching, e.g. when each person can be assigned to at most $k$ different jobs: just change the capacities of the edge from $s$ to each person from $1$ to $k$ (the capacity of the edge from each person to each job remains $1$, so that each person is assigned at most once to each job).

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) and also [networkx documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.min_cost_flow.html), the min-cost flow problem has another input called "demand", which is the amount that should be sent from $s$ to $t$. In this case, the demand should probably be $n$ (the number of people).

Comment: @llllvvuu, there are typically many solutions to such a problem, some integral and some not.